# Why do we use context in Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have used `context` in `groovy` in and as:

```
def gu = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
```

What does it refer to?

Comment: Probably `context` holds information about the environment and is required to freely navigate in the mentioned environment.

Comment: context available in groovy scripts in SoapUI is the context of executions of a test case/test suit. Search more about it. @Opal should add that as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Context holds information about the environment and is required to freely navigate in the mentioned environment.

@dmahapatro:

> context available in groovy scripts in SoapUI is the context of executions of a test case/test suit.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/the-soapui-object-model.html):

> When scripting inside some kind of "run", there is always a context variable available for getting/setting context-specific variables. The contexts are:

- SubmitContext - available within one submit of a request
- TestRunContext - available from within all scripts in a TestCase run
- LoadTestRunContext - available in LoadTest setup/tearDown scripts and
  from the exectued TestCase context via the LoadTestContext context
  variable
- MockRunContext - available in MockService startup/shutdown scripts
  and MockOperation/MockResponse dispatch scripts

> All these inherit from the PropertyExpansionContext interface which
>   has methods for setting/getting properties and an expand method which
>   can be used to expand arbitrary strings containing
>   Property-Expansions, read more on this in the soapUI User-Guide.